# Oracle SQL Function for Max Col Length returning NULLs when called

Tags: sql, oracle

I have build a function that should return the max value stored in each column (not the max value allowed but what data is actually there) of tables specified. Running the code in isolation returns results as server output when called it only shows NULLs for all tables.

**FUNCTION:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COL_MAX_LENGTH(table_name VARCHAR2, column_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN INTEGER 
    IS
    v_ln INTEGER;

BEGIN

   FOR r IN (
            select table_name, column_name
            from all_tab_cols
            WHERE owner = '' --MY TABLE OWNER VALUE
            AND table_name = '' --MY TABLE NAME VALUE
            AND column_id IS NOT NULL
            )
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(length('||r.column_name||')) from '||r.table_name into v_ln;
      dbms_output.put_line('Table: '||r.table_name||', Column: '||r.column_name||', v_ln: '||v_ln);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN v_ln;

END;
```

**QUERY TO CALL FUNCTION:**

```
    SELECT COL_MAX_LENGTH(table_name,column_name)
    FROM all_tab_cols ATC
```

Have tried to specify different data type, amend all the parameters in loop and outside but nothing works

Comment: well you have a loop and v_ln is only going to return the value last assigned from the last loop iteration.

Comment: Not a good ideea to have the parameters for the function named table_name and column_name. There ar naming conventions like prefixing the parameter names with p_, or i_ for in params, o_ for out params and io_ for in-out params. Plus, I think the select should have where owner=p_owner and table_name=p_table_name and column_name=p_column name. Yes, for the function should have a parameter for column name. Otherwise it makes no sense to return an integer. And I'd rather be more generous and return a number. The select used in the for loop will return no rows.

Comment: Please post reproducible example. Also note that naming input parameters in the same way as column names in SQL statement will lead to unexpected results because of [Name resolution rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09): *If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name takes precedence.* You code effectively loops through all the tables accessible to the author of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function code is wrong. It is useless to loop in the function; query (that runs through all columns in desired table) does that "loop" itself.

Therefore, just select max length and return it.

Should be something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION COL_MAX_LENGTH (p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_column_name VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN INTEGER
  3  IS
  4     v_ln  INTEGER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(length(' || p_column_name || ')) from ' || p_table_name
  7        INTO v_ln;
  8
  9     RETURN v_ln;
 10  END;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SELECT table_name, column_name, COL_MAX_LENGTH (table_name, column_name) max_len
  2    FROM all_tab_cols ATC
  3   WHERE table_name = 'DEPT';

TABLE_NAME                     COLUMN_NAME                       MAX_LEN
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
DEPT                           LOC                                     8
DEPT                           DNAME                                  10
DEPT                           DEPTNO                                  2

SQL>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant thanks! Love that the answer is less complicated than I was trying to make it with loops etc.